# JSON structure with perl

Tags: json, perl

Have a JSON structure that looks as follows:

```
{"gene_res":{"gene":[{"gname":{"variant":[{"annotation":"","an":2}]}}]}}
```

My code:

```
use warnings; 
use diagnostics; 
use strict; 
 use JSON::MaybeXS; 
     if ($#ARGV!=0){
    warn "ERROR: Expecting a JSON file as input\n";
    exit;
    }

  my ($INFILE)=@ARGV;
  my $json;

 {
    local $/; #Enable 'slurp' mode
    open my $IFH, "<", "$INFILE";
    $json= <$IFH>;
    close $IFH;
 }


printingMeta($json);

sub printingMeta
 {
    my $hash = decode_json($_[0]);
    my $gene='';

    foreach my $arrayref (@{$hash->{gene_res}->{gene}})
    {
            foreach my $gene (keys %{$arrayref})
            {
                    print "$gene\n";
                    #This works, I get "name"


            }

    }
```

I am not able find a way to reach to an/annotations. 
In the above example gname is an array, so I can have many "gnames", with many diff values.
I need something like this:

```
foreach my $item (@{$hash->{gene_res}{$gene}{variant}})
```

But this does not works. Gets error Not a HASH reference at .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@{ $hash->{gene_res}{$gene_name}{variant} }
```

is wrong because the layer is an array, not a hash. it needs to be

```
@{ $hash->{gene_res}[$gene_idx]{$gene_name}{variant} }
```

The data structure is rather odd, so it's no surprise you're having problems wrapping your head around it.

So,

```
sub printingMeta {
    my ($data) = @_;
    for my $genes (@{ $data->{gene_res}->{gene} }) {
        for my $gene_name (keys(%$genes)) {
            print($gene_name, "\n");
            my $gene = $genes->{$gene_name};
            for my $variant (@{ $gene->{variant} }) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Rest of the program cleaned up:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

use JSON qw( decode_json );

die("usage: $0 json_file\n")
    if @ARGV != 1;

my $json; { local $/; $json = <>; }
my $data = decode_json($json);
printingMeta($data);
```

Comment: Thanks!! The above worked!! The data structure can be (perhaps should be fixed), but its how I am getting the out put from REST and its beyond my control

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you are understanding the data structure properly.  Using `Data::Dumper` to print out the data structure is a good first step to understanding what the structure looks like.

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($hash);
```

Produces the following output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'gene_res' => {
                          'gene' => [
                                      {
                                        'gname' => {
                                                     'variant' => [
                                                                    {
                                                                      'an' => 2,
                                                                      'annotation' => ''
                                                                    }
                                                                  ]
                                                   }
                                      }
                                    ]
                        }
        };
```

I have modified your `printingMeta` subroutine to access the `annotation` and `an` fields.

```
sub printingMeta {
    my $hash = decode_json($_[0]);

    foreach my $gene ( @{ $hash->{gene_res}{gene}} ) {

        foreach my $variant ( @{ $gene->{gname}{variant}} ) {

            print $variant->{an}, "\t", $variant->{annotation}, "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve but the above code will allow you to access the `annotation` and `an` fields.

Comment: Thanks for giving the idea of using Data::Dumper. Will use this now. The gname is a value so i wont know what it would be, the key that i know are gene_res, gene, variants. Sorry if the example, explanation was not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to access nested data structures if you keep an intermediate variable pointing at each level of the structure as you dive into it

It's also imperative that you use `Data::Dumper` (or preferably `Data::Dump`, which generates less sprawling output, but isn't a core module and so may need to be installed) to examine the data structure that you have to deal with at each level. That way it is obvious - if it begins with a brace `{` then it's a hash reference, or if it begins with a square bracket `[` then it's an array reference

For instance, if I use `dd $genes` to show the result of

```
my $genes = $href->{gene_res}{gene};
```

then I get this output

```
[{ gname => { variant => [{ an => 2, annotation => "" }] } }]
```

which shows immediately that it's an array reference

It doesn't help that you have named a hash reference `$arrayref`! In this code I have carefully used singular nouns for hash references and plurals for array references

You can also use `each` to fetch key/value pairs from a hash at the same time

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use JSON;
use Data::Dump;

my $json = '{"gene_res":{"gene":[{"gname":{"variant":[{"annotation":"","an":2}]}}]}}';

my $href = decode_json($json);

my $genes = $href->{gene_res}{gene};

for my $gene (@$genes) {

    #dd 'gene', $gene;

    while ( my ($gname, $variant) = each %$gene ) {

        print "gname      = $gname\n";
        #dd 'variant', $variant;

        my $variants = $variant->{variant};

        for my $variant ( @$variants ) {

            #dd 'variant', $variant;

            print "annotation = $variant->{annotation}\n";
            print "an         = $variant->{an}\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for emphasizing the use of Data::Dumper.  I am not clear about the variable name, @{$hash->{gene_res}->{gene}} this is pointing to the (anonymous)  array ? Nice idea to use key/val pair together.

Comment: @deep: Okay I've added a paragraph to my solution that I hope clarifies that